# Round Commerce Price: in tpl.php or template.php

Tags: theming, commerce

Currently I'm using Commerce and Commerce Multicurrency to our currency in Indonesia.

Sometimes there is a price to numbers that are not rounded.

With print render ($ content ['product: commerce_price']) I get the original price.

I've tried to edit the tpl.php file and the results are as desired.

```
number_format (round ($ price, -4), 0);
```

2,511,000 into 2,500,000
2,565,000 into 2,600,000

But after some reading and hopefully not misread. That is not good in tpl.php, but should be in template.php or modules.

Please advise to help me.

Comment: after searching all night, and I found the answer by creating a custom module based on [this][1]

    function bulat($bilangan){

 $bulat = number_format(round($bilangan,-4), 0); 
 return $bulat;
 
    }

and print it in my node.tpl.php. I hope the way I use it correctly and safely


  [1]: https://drupal.org/node/81681#comment-150049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to adjust currency formatting, using the relevant Commerce currency hooks, is with

[hook_commerce_currency_info_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.api.php/function/hook_commerce_currency_info_alter/7)

and adding your own [commerce_currency_format](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.module/function/commerce_currency_format/7) handler

e.g:

```
/**
 * hook_commerce_currency_info_alter
 * 
 * Add custom currency format to selected currencies
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_info_alter(&$currencies){
  $currencies['IDR']['format_callback'] = 'MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_format';
}

/**
 * Currency format callback
 *
 * Remove decimal places from output
 * while keeping commerce_amount_to_decimal formatting the same
 *
 * See: commerce_currency_format
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_currency_format($amount, $currency, $object = NULL, $convert = TRUE) {

  // Format the price as a number.
  // In our case, we remove decimal places
  $price = number_format(commerce_currency_round(abs($amount), $currency), 0, $currency['decimal_separator'], $currency['thousands_separator']);

  // Establish the replacement values to format this price for its currency.
  $replacements = array(
    '@code_before' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'before' ? $currency['code'] : '',
    '@symbol_before' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'before' ? $currency['symbol'] : '',
    '@price' => $price,
    '@symbol_after' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'after' ? $currency['symbol'] : '',
    '@code_after' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'after' ? $currency['code'] : '',
    '@negative' => $amount < 0 ? '-' : '',
    '@symbol_spacer' => $currency['symbol_spacer'],
    '@code_spacer' => $currency['code_spacer'],
  );

  return trim(t('@code_before@code_spacer@negative@symbol_before@price@symbol_spacer@symbol_after@code_spacer@code_after', $replacements));
}
```

Comment: thanks @david-thomas for your advice. right now i still trying THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) after this i will try yours. because i'm still stuck

Comment: Preprocess node will only affect node output, you should use the above method to ensure the currency is formatted correctly in _all_ places where currency is output, e.g order admin line items etc...

Comment: @DavidThomas Though you have voted negatively to my answer & have written great solution for this, but as per question asked by him I answered correctly & I don't see any reason behind negative vote...

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm trying the solution you provide. I managed to modify prices and price variations were able to take changed. thank you very much for the solution. now I'm trying to learn more deeply. I'm very interested in learning more deeply, where should I start reading something like this?

Comment: @mbahol, perhaps start with reading the API documentation at: http://api.drupalcommerce.org/ Once you know what hooks are available, the best approach becomes much clearer.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for your help. now i can round($amount,-4) and its render perfectly. could you give me an advice how should i check original currency code. right now i'm trying this if($currency['code']=='USD') {
   $amount = round($amount,-4);
  }

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you have done it by making some module. But still I will tell you my way to doing it.

As you want to print the value after rounding it in your node.tpl.php, you can go for implementing [THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) function in your template.php file of the theme which you are using. Replace THEME with your theme name in there.

Now implement something like this,

```
function indiareads_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  if ($node = menu_get_object()){
    if($node->type == 'YOUR_PRODUCT_DISPLAY_TYPE'){
      $product_id = $node->FIELD_PRODUCT_REFERENCE['und'][0]['product_id'];
      $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
      $price = $product->commerce_price['und'][0]['amount'];
      $rounded_price = number_format(round($price,-4), 0);
      $vars['rounded_price'] = $rounded_price;
    }
  }
}
```

Replace YOUR_PRODUCT_DISPLAY_TYPE with the name of content type which is displaying your product & FIELD_PRODUCT_REFERENCE with the name of field of that content type which reference the commerce product.

After this when you will go to **node.tpl.php**, you will have `$rounded_price` variable available to print where ever you want.

I am writing this for better understanding of the system even if you have done that, so that if somebody comes searching can get help.

Comment: thanks @RajeevK. right now i'm trying your solution. but still stuck in render and only work with USD price.

Comment: @mbahlol - Try a bit more & you will find solution :)

Comment: This will only affect node output, resulting in inconsistent pricing display throughout the site.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have just given the example for the sake of understanding to do something like this from template.php, which he was asking. And if I have particular node display type & I need to show the price at some place in some format, this is the way I follow...